# How to make REST calls to Tableau

Tags: rest, tableau-api

I need to make REST requests to Tableau to upload and download data sources and other requests.

In the documentation mentioned [here](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_concepts_fundamentals.htm#using_uris_for_resources), it says that to make a REST request you need.

1. Server Name
2. SiteID
3. Workspace/Group ID

Where can I get these 3 things? I am new thus not familiar with the tableau platform.
Below is my Tableau Dashboard:
[image]

Comment: I recommend using Tableau Server Client python library that simplifies the REST api. https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you've figured this out based on some of your other questions but here is the answer for anyone else searching.

1. Server name = your server's ip address or if using Tableau Online, the first portion of your url when you login.
   `10ay.online.tableau.com` for the `GET` call of
   `https://10ay.online.tableau.com/api/3.12/sites/site-id/projects/project-id`
2. Site ID can be returned using a `POST` in your API authentication call. Using the server name above the `POST` call would look like this `https://10ay.online.tableau.com/api/3.4/auth/signin` You will need to add some info to the `POST` body that will look like this.

> {
> "credentials": {
> "personalAccessTokenName": "YOURTOKENNAME",
> "personalAccessTokenSecret": "YOURTOKENSECRET",
> "site": {
> "contentUrl": "YOURSITE"
> }
> }
> }

3. You don't necessarily need the group-id unless you are returning group specific info like user/group relationships. Use this in a `GET` call to return your group IDs by name. `https://10ay.online.tableau.com/api/3.12/sites/site-id/groups`